# Conversion from not equal to equal in nat

Tags: coq

I have function,whose output is some natural number.I have proved a lemma,that output of this function cannot be zero. It means output is equal to some natural number S m.I want to convert the above lemma.

```
Theorem greater:forall (m :nat)(l:list nat),
 m=?0=false ->
 0=? (f1 + m)=false-> 
 (f1 + m)= S m.
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement you entered does not type check. Regardless, I don't see how it could hold -- for instance, if by `l` you mean `f1 : nat`, then the statement would imply that `3 = 2`.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Theorem greater:forall (m :nat)(f1:nat),
 m=?0=false ->
 0=? (f1 + m)=false->
 (f1 + m)= S m.
Admitted.

Lemma contra : False.
Proof.
pose proof (greater 1 2 eq_refl eq_refl).
easy.
Qed.
```

Proving that something that is not zero is a successor can be done as follows:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Lemma not_zero_succ :
  forall n, n <> 0 ->
  exists m, n = S m.
Proof. destruct n as [|n]; eauto; easy. Qed.
```

**Edit** The complete statement you wrote below is also contradictory:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint lt_numb (n: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | h::tl =>
    if h <? n then S (lt_numb n tl) else lt_numb n tl
  end.

Fixpoint greatest (large: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match large with
  | O => 0
  | S m' => (lt_numb large l) + (greatest m' l)
  end.

Definition change (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => l
  | h::tl => if n <? h then l else n::tl
  end.

Fixpoint g_value (elements: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | [n] => n
  | h :: l =>
    match elements with
    | O => h
    | S elements' => g_value elements' (change h l)
    end
  end.

Theorem no_elements : forall (m n z :nat)(l:list nat),
    m=?0=false -> greatest(g_value (length (n :: l)) (n :: l) + m) (n :: l) = (S z).
Proof. Admitted.

Goal False.
pose proof (no_elements 1 0 1 [] eq_refl).
simpl in H.
discriminate.
Qed.
```

Comment: @rosijavi I am sorry, I am still having trouble understanding what you want to do. Can you write a self-contained, corrected statement of `greater` that I can run directly in Coq, and put it in the original question? I cannot run `m_greater` or `greater_f2` because you did not include the definitions of `f1` or `f2`.

Comment: @rosijavi The definitions of `change_greater` and `greater_element` are useful, but they are still not enough: I cannot relate them to the explanation you wrote above about `f1` and `m`. You need to **edit** your original question and include **all** the relevant code to diagnose your problem. It should be possible to copy the code from your question, paste it in a Coq file and run until reaching the point where you are having trouble.

Comment: @rosijavi Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, the statement you wrote there is contradictory. I updated the answer with a counter example.

Comment: With the help of above functions ,I am proving following two lemmas,but facing problem in proving . Or they provable?                                                         
Theorem g_value_len1 :forall (n a :nat)(l:list nat),
(g_value (length (a :: l))
(change n (a :: l)) <= n).

Theorem g_value_len2 :forall (n a :nat)(l:list nat),
(g_value (length (a :: l))
(change n (a :: l)) = 0).@Arthur Azevedo De Amorim